# Need help understanding int padding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

Tags: c, memory, cs50, bmp

I am doing Harvard CS50x practice problem bottumup.c which requires us to change an image from upside down to top side down. We have to manipulate our BMP file somehow to change its orientation. What I don't understand is this line of code

`int padding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;`

I know that each color RGB is one byte and I know we need to add padding? Also, how does modulo help out in this scenario?

Thank you

I tried researching on google but I still can't exactly understand. I don't understand the purpose of why we need to use modulo and why we use it twice.

Comment: You might start with pen&paper and write a sequence of numbers and then calculate the result of that expression for each number. How does the result change from one number to the next?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm fairly certain the outside `% 4` does absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Jason it changes `4` to `0`. There are never `4` bytes of padding.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah I was just testing you =]

Comment: @Jason I usually calculate the line length and allocate the array accordingly. `stride = (((bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) - 1) | 3) + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

`bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)` is the number of bytes in one row of the array (a row containing `bi.biWidth` elements of type `RGBTRIPLE`.

`(bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4` is how many more bytes that length is than a multiple of 4.

`4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4)` is how many bytes are needed to add to that to make it the next multiple of 4. If the length is 0, 1, 2, or 3 bytes more than a multiple of 4, this expression is 4, 3, 2, or 1.

However, if the length is a multiple of four (the first expression above is 0 and the second is 4), we do not want to pad it; we want to add zero bytes. So `(4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4` is used to produce 0, 3, 2, or 1, respectively.

Thus `padding` is set to the number of bytes to pad a row by to make it a multiple of four bytes. Presumably, the program is making the array rows a nice size so that they work well with hardware characteristics or other software.

The expression can be reduced. `- (size_t) (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4` or `- (size_t) (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) & 3` produces the same value. `bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)` typically already has type `size_t`, but, if `bi.biWidth` is some long signed type, it might not, so the cast to `size_t` ensures we have the length as an unsigned type. If its low two bits are 00, 01, 10, or 11, negating it in an unsigned integer type produces a value whose low two bits are 00, 11, 10, or 01, and then taking the low two bits yields the desired value. (Actually, casting to `unsigned int` might technically be safer, since the C standard would allow an implementation where `size_t` is narrower than `int` and one’s complement is used, which would screw up the calculation.)

Comment: Mea culpa - I posted the comment on the wrong answer!  As you can see if you follow the user profile for the user who wrote the other answer, I was posting on theirs.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to touch the width its very easy, you need just to add this little code here:

bi.biHeight = -bi.biHeight;

before writing to outfile

hoops that this helps you!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).